imported package source code versus python virtual environment
I'm using PyCharm IDE and using flask_paginate module. From within PyCharm I've installed flask_paginate but when I see the declaration for this module, __init__.py open from C:\Users\05554F744\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages.
Should the source code for flask_paginate not reside in the venv folder within project folder? Does venv  not contain source code for all imported modules?
If I want to run my application in another machine, I need to install flask_paginate again? What is the solution instead?

You probably used the command pip install flask_paginate, try using python -m pip install flask_paginate from within the virtual environment.

perhaps your editor is pointing to the wrong python interpreter. In vscode the editor can use a different interpreter from the terminal window

I tried "python -m pip install flask_paginate" from within venv at command line but do not see the package being installed in venv.

Normally you would provide a requirements.txt with all the dependencies, which then can be easily installed with pip on any device. Requirements file format. The command to install a requirements file is
pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt. About Pycharm you should check the selected python interpreter in your project structure to be the one in the venv.

I think the python interpreter in my project structure does match the one in venv (version matches)  . I'm not having problem in running app from within PyCharm. For running in another m/c , I understand the solution is requirements.txt. Is there a way, I can have the module installed inside the venv instead of C:\Users\05554F744\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages ?

Yes you can definitely install packages in venv, actually thats the normal way to do it because normally you dont want you packages to be installed globally. This should provide all the information you need to install packages in a venv.

Here is the Pycharm Documentation for using a venv
